# Using a CRTP approach for loading OpenGL programs

Tags: c++, c++11, template, inheritance, opengl

I wanted to try using CRTP *(also new for me)* to try making the loading of shared resources implicit. *(Specifically I'm using it for loading OpenGl shader programs)*

This will also help separate some of the boiler plate setup code *(combining shaders into a program)* from the more specific setup code *(assigning locations for shader uniforms)*, and making sure that no one program is loaded more than once.

If it applies *(pretty certain it does)*, what concepts/ fundamentals am I missing/ not seeing?

By using statics I understand that this isn't thread safe, however I don't think I'll be using multiple threads- but even with that said, any ideas/ tips on that matter would still be much appreciated!

The code lightly uses the `Mesh` class from the online tutorial series [Learning Modern 3D Graphics Programming](http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/) by Jason L. McKesson, and the source code for that can be found [here](https://bitbucket.org/alfonse/gltut/downloads) under framework. The shaders being used are found under Tut 10/ data *(but I will post them as they are very short)*. It also uses glm, freeglut and other libraries found in the glsdk folder of the source code.

CRTP base header, ProgramBase.h

```
const std::string LOCALFILEDIR = "data\\";
const int PROJECTION_BLOCK_INDEX = 2;

template<class CustomProgram> class ProgramBase
{
public:
    static GLuint program_location();
protected:
    ProgramBase();
    ~ProgramBase(){}
private:
    static GLuint LoadShader(GLenum shader_type_e, const std::string &base_shader_filename);
    static GLuint CreateProgram(const std::vector<GLuint> &shader_locations);

    static GLuint program_location_;
};
```

The idea is that every `CustomProgram` will have to define at least three members in order for the below code to work:

- `vertex_shader_names_` A container of vertex shaders names to be found and linked
- `fragment_shader_names_`A list of fragment shaders names to be found and linked
- `Init()` A function specific to shaders named above that will find uniforms

```
template<class CustomProgram> ProgramBase<CustomProgram>::ProgramBase()
{
    if(program_location_ == -1)
    {
        std::vector<GLuint> shader_locations;
        for(const std::string& name : CustomProgram::vertex_shader_names_)
        {
            shader_locations.push_back(LoadShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER, name));
        }
        for(const std::string& name : CustomProgram::fragment_shader_names_)
        {
            shader_locations.push_back(LoadShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, name));
        }

        program_location_ = CreateProgram(shader_locations);
        CustomProgram::Init();
    }
}

template<class CustomProgram> GLuint ProgramBase<CustomProgram>::LoadShader(
    GLenum shader_type_e, 
    const std::string &base_shader_filename)
{
    std::ifstream shader_file((LOCALFILEDIR + base_shader_filename).c_str());
    if(!shader_file.is_open())
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("Could not find the file " + base_shader_filename);
    }
    std::stringstream shader_data;
    shader_data << shader_file.rdbuf();
    shader_file.close();

    try
    {
        return glutil::CompileShader(shader_type_e, shader_data.str());
    }
    catch(std::exception &e)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", e.what());
        throw;
    }
}
template<class CustomProgram> GLuint ProgramBase<CustomProgram>::CreateProgram(
    const std::vector<GLuint> &shader_locations)
{
    try
    {
        GLuint prog = glutil::LinkProgram(shader_locations);
        std::for_each(shader_locations.begin(), shader_locations.end(), glDeleteShader);
        return prog;
    }
    catch(std::exception &e)
    {
        std::for_each(shader_locations.begin(), shader_locations.end(), glDeleteShader);
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", e.what());
        throw;
    }
}

template<class CustomProgram> GLuint ProgramBase<CustomProgram>::program_location()
{
    return program_location_;
}

template<class CustomProgram> GLuint ProgramBase<CustomProgram>::program_location_ = -1;
```

---

One program I incorporate is a program which simply positions the model relative to the camera, and then to clip space before drawing a single color. `(this is pretty much directly from the tutorial)`

PosTransform.vert

```
#version 330
layout(location = 0) in vec3 position;
uniform mat4 modelToCameraMatrix;
uniform Projection
{
    mat4 cameraToClipMatrix;
};
void main()
{
    gl_Position = cameraToClipMatrix * (modelToCameraMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0));
}
```

UniformColor.frag

```
#version 330
uniform vec4 objectColor;
out vec4 outputColor;
void main()
{
    outputColor = objectColor;
}
```

---

This is the class I've defined for it. BasicProgram.h

```
class BasicProgram : ProgramBase<BasicProgram>
{
    friend class ProgramBase<BasicProgram>;
public:
    BasicProgram()
        : model_matrix_(glm::mat4(1.0f)), color_vector_(glm::vec4(1.0f))
    { }

    BasicProgram(glm::mat4& model_matrix, glm::vec4& color_vector)
        : model_matrix_(model_matrix), color_vector_(color_vector)
    { }

    void Render(Framework::Mesh* mesh);
    glm::mat4 model_matrix();
    void set_model_matrix(glm::mat4 model_matrix);
    glm::vec4 color_vector();
    void set_color_vector(glm::vec4 color_vector);
private:
    static void Init();

    glm::mat4 model_matrix_;
    glm::vec4 color_vector_;

    static const std::array<std::string,1> vertex_shader_names_;
    static const std::array<std::string,1> fragment_shader_names_;

    static GLuint model_matrix_unif_;
    static GLuint color_vector_unif_;
};
```

And the guts

```
void BasicProgram::Render(Framework::Mesh* mesh)
{
    glUseProgram(program_location());
    glUniformMatrix4fv(model_matrix_unif_, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(model_matrix_));
    glUniform4fv(color_vector_unif_, 1,  glm::value_ptr(color_vector_));
    mesh->Render();
    glUseProgram(0);
}
void BasicProgram::Init()
{
    model_matrix_unif_  = glGetUniformLocation(program_location(), "modelToCameraMatrix");
    color_vector_unif_  = glGetUniformLocation(program_location(), "objectColor");

    GLuint projectionBlock = glGetUniformBlockIndex(program_location(), "Projection");
    glUniformBlockBinding(program_location(), projectionBlock, PROJECTION_BLOCK_INDEX);
}
const std::array<std::string,1> BasicProgram::vertex_shader_names_ = 
{
    "PosTransform.vert",
};
const std::array<std::string,1> BasicProgram::fragment_shader_names_ = 
{
    "UniformColor.frag",
};
glm::mat4 BasicProgram::model_matrix()
{
    return glm::mat4(model_matrix_);
}
void BasicProgram::set_model_matrix(glm::mat4 model_matrix)
{
    model_matrix_ = glm::mat4(model_matrix);
}
glm::vec4 BasicProgram::color_vector()
{
    return glm::vec4(color_vector_);
}
void BasicProgram::set_color_vector(glm::vec4 color_vector)
{
    color_vector_ = glm::vec4(color_vector);
}
```

Comment: I tend to avoid CRTP as much as possible, because it absolutely *kills* compile-time.

Comment: That's a bit of an over generalization. It very much depends on how it's applied in a codebase. Relative to many other template techniques it's not even particularly expensive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Overall, I'd say it is well done. You have properly implemented CRTP. But I'm a bit skeptical about your choice. If you have a lot of shader program implementations that are included in a lot of places, your compile times will suffer a bit and the generated binary is going to be bigger. Also, any change to `ProgramBase` might implicate a next-to-full recompile of the project.

In this particular case, I would have resorted to simple inheritance. As far as I can tell, the only two virtual methods you would need are one to get a reference to the set of `vertex_shader_names_` and one for `fragment_shader_names_`. Perhaps also a `virtual Init()` but that work can be done in the constructor of the child class. A public virtual destructor or a protected non-virtual one. That's all. Of course that the virtual calls are more expensive during runtime, but here you are only executing them once, during startup/initialization, so there is little reason to optimize and tradeoff for longer compile times and bigger binaries. Also, with simple inheritance, code would become a little simpler and you could easily get rid of the statics (not that there is a problem with threading, GL can only run from a single thread anyways).

---

**Some other minor details in the code:**

In the first constructor of `BasicProgram`, you don't need to explicitly call `vec4/mat(1.0f)`, that's just creating a useless temporary object:

```
BasicProgram()
    : model_matrix_(1.0f), color_vector_(1.0f)
{ }
```

In the second constructor, you are making copies of the parameters. `move` doesn't apply here because the GLM objects are just arrays of `float`s. So you can continue passing the parameters by reference. But since there is no intent in modifying them, make the references `const` to document that:

```
BasicProgram(const glm::mat4& model_matrix, const glm::vec4& color_vector)
    : model_matrix_(model_matrix), color_vector_(color_vector)
{ }
```

Again, when returning the values, that constructor style cast in useless:

```
return glm::vec4(color_vector_);
```

`color_vector_` is already a `glm::vec4`. Just `return color_vector_`.

You are using a mixed `snake_case` and `PascalCase` naming style for the methods. `snake_case` being used by lightweight get/set methods only.
Personally, I don't appreciate that mixing of styles. A method is a method, regardless of its purpose, so I think it makes more sense naming all methods uniformly. Then identify lightweight accessors with the traditional `get/Get`, `set/Set` prefix.

Comment: Thanks for the tips! In terms of style, for the most part I was trying to follow the [google style guide](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.html)

Comment: @Calpratt - Yes, I'm familiar with that. The `get/set` method naming is one of the few disagreements I have with that guide. Like I said, it doesn't make sense to me to change the *naming convention* of a method based on its purpose. The *name* of the method is what indicates the purpose. But if you are comfortable with that style, feel free to continue using it. This is certainly a subjective matter that is mostly based on opinion.

Answer (score 4):

Nothing major, but here are a few things you could change:

- Since you don't define any special constructor/operator= in `ProgramBase`, you don't need to explicitly define its destructor. You can let the compiler do the job for you.
- In C++, `std::ifstream` [has a constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream/basic_ifstream) that can take an `std::string` instead of a `const char*`. Therefore, you need not call `c_str` anymore in the following line:

  ```
  std::ifstream shader_file((LOCALFILEDIR + base_shader_filename).c_str());
  ```
- When opening a file, the idiomatic way t check for errors is to use `operator!` which may catch more errors [citation needed] than `is_open`:

  ```
  std::ifstream shader_file(LOCALFILEDIR + base_shader_filename);
  if(!shader_file)
  {
      throw std::runtime_error("Could not find the file " + base_shader_filename);
  }
  ```
- To clarify your intent, you could use an `std::ostringstream` instead of an `std::stringstream` in the method `ProgramBase<CustomProgram>::LoadShader`.
- This line seems a little bit C-ish:

  ```
  fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", e.what());
  ```

  Couldn't you simply replace it by this one?

  ```
  std::cerr << e.what();
  ```
- Please, only use FULL_CAPS names for macros, not for constants in general. A usual goal of the FULL_CAPS case in C/C++ is to know with a glance that there may be something fishy going on. Since macros were often used to define constants in C89, many people still write their constants in FULL_CAPS case, but pretty please, try to only use this case for macros :)
- You could use constructor delegation to slightly simplify your constructors:

  ```
  BasicProgram()
      // Delegate to the other BasicProgram constructor
      : BasicProgram(glm::mat4(1.0f), glm::vec4(1.0f))
  { }

  BasicProgram(glm::mat4& model_matrix, glm::vec4& color_vector)
      : model_matrix_(model_matrix), color_vector_(color_vector)
  { }
  ```